Obtaining the UID of a Mifare Classic RFID tag on an Android phone via Kotlin
I have no experience with creating Android apps at all but I would like to build a simple app that does a few things based on the UID of a Mifare Classic tag that I present to the NFC reader.
I spent the last days digging through the internet and ended up with the implementation below:
AndroidManifest.xml
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
...
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            android:launchMode="singleTop"> <!-- Ensure singleTop for NFC to deliver intents -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                 android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                 android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity>
...

/res/xml/nfc_tech_filter.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>


MainActivity.kt
...
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter
import android.nfc.Tag
import android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic
import android.nfc.tech.NfcA

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter
     
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Initialize NFC Adapter
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)
...
    }
    
...
    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)

        // Retrieve the NFC tag from the intent
        val tagFromIntent: Tag? = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)

        if (tagFromIntent != null) {
            Log.e("NFC_TAG", "NFC tag found in the intent")
        } else {
            Log.e("NFC_TAG", "No NFC tag found in the intent")
        }
    }

The app is supposed to run on an old Sony Xperia Compact smartphone with Android 9. 
When I test the app on this phone and present a Mifare Classic 1K RFID card I always get the "No NFC tag found in the intent" output.
However, when I use apps such as TagInfo or MIFARE Classic the UID of the cards for testing is shown. NFC Tools even shows NfcA and MifareClassic as available technologies.
What am I missing in my implementation?
Update 16.09.:
I found a resource online (NFCReader - mueller-ma github) that is an implementation of a Kotlin app that gives the user information about RFID tags. It does more than I need but served as a good basis. I still do not know the exact issues with my approach but also this version does not recognize the tags as Mifare Classic. As it is still able to determine the UID from my "unknown" tags I have all I need for my little project and was able to have this function working.

As you are initialising the NFC Adapter are you doing anything with enabledForegroundDispatch ? If yes then show that code instead of ...

You are using the Intent-based NFC detection technology that may be not the best option, I'm preferring the more modern Reader Mode for accessing NFC tags.
As there are a lot of questions here on Stackoverflow.com regarding this topic I'm providing a sample app how to work with the Reader Mode. The complete (Java) source is available here: https://github.com/AndroidCrypto/AndroidBasicNfcReader.
I read that you are working with Kotlin but in AndroidStudio it is just a simple click to convert the class to Kotlin code.
To run the code you need to add the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" /> line to your AndroidManifest.xml and that's it:
package de.androidcrypto.androidbasicnfcreader;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.ToneGenerator;
import android.nfc.FormatException;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
import android.nfc.tech.NfcA;
import android.nfc.tech.NfcV;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback {

    private TextView textView;
    private NfcAdapter myNfcAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        myNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    }

    /**
     * Please note: this method is NOT running in User Interface (UI) Thread, so you cannot write directly
     * to any TextView, Toasts or other elements on your activity. Please use runOnUiThread instead:
     * runOnUiThread(() -> {
     * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     * });
     *
     * @param tag
     */
    @Override
    public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
        String output = "";
        String lineDivider = "--------------------";
        output += "NFC tag detected" + "\n";

        // examine tag
        byte[] tagUid = tag.getId();
        output += "Tag UID length: " + tagUid.length  + " UID: " + bytesToHex(tagUid) + "\n";
        String[] techlist = tag.getTechList();
        output += lineDivider + "\n";
        output += "The TechList contains " + techlist.length + " entry/ies:" + "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < techlist.length; i++) {
            output += "Entry " + i + ": " + techlist[i]  + "\n";
        }
        output += lineDivider + "\n";
        output += tag.toString()  + "\n";
        output += lineDivider + "\n";
        // if the tag uses the NfcA class I'm connecting the tag now this class
        // I'm trying to use the NfcA class, if it is not supported by the tag an exception is thrown
        NfcA nfcA = null;
        nfcA = NfcA.get(tag);
        if (nfcA == null) {
            output += "This tag is NOT supporting the NfcA class" + "\n";
            output += lineDivider + "\n";
        } else {
            // I'm trying to get more information's about the tag and connect to the tag
            byte[] atqa = nfcA.getAtqa();
            byte sak = (byte) nfcA.getSak();
            int maxTransceiveLength = nfcA.getMaxTransceiveLength();
            output += "-= NfcA Technology =-" + "\n";
            output += "ATQA: " + bytesToHex(atqa) + "\n";
            output += "SAK: " + byteToHex(sak) + "\n";
            output += "maxTransceiveLength: " + maxTransceiveLength + "\n";
            output += lineDivider + "\n";

            try {
                nfcA.connect();
                output += "Connected to the tag using NfcA technology" + "\n";
                output += lineDivider + "\n";
                nfcA.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                output += "NfcA connect to tag IOException: " + e.getMessage() + "\n";
                output += lineDivider + "\n";
            }
        }

        // connect to NfcV class (e.g. ICODE tags use this technology
        NfcV nfcV = null;
        nfcV = NfcV.get(tag);
        if (nfcV == null) {
            output += "This tag is NOT supporting the NfcV class" + "\n";
            output += lineDivider + "\n";
        } else {
            byte dsfId = nfcV.getDsfId();
            int maxTransceiveLength = nfcV.getMaxTransceiveLength();
            output += "-= NfcV Technology =-" + "\n";
            output += "DsfId: " + byteToHex(dsfId) + "\n";
            output += "maxTransceiveLength: " + maxTransceiveLength + "\n";
            output += lineDivider + "\n";

            try {
                nfcV.connect();
                output += "Connected to the tag using NfcV technology" + "\n";
                output += lineDivider + "\n";
                nfcV.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                output += "NfcV connect to tag IOException: " + e.getMessage() + "\n";
                output += lineDivider + "\n";
            }
        }

        // trying to read NDEF content
        Ndef ndef = null;
        ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        if (ndef == null) {
            output += "This tag is NOT supporting the NDEF class" + "\n";
            output += lineDivider + "\n";
        } else {
            try {
                ndef.connect();
                output += "Connected to the tag using NDEF technology" + "\n";
                output += lineDivider + "\n";
                NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getNdefMessage();
                String ndefMessageString = ndefMessage.toString();
                byte[] ndefMessageBytes = ndefMessage.toByteArray();
                output += "NDEF message: " + ndefMessageString + "\n";
                if (ndefMessageBytes != null) {
                    output += "NDEF message: " + bytesToHex(ndefMessageBytes) + "\n";
                    output += "NDEF message: " + new String(ndefMessageBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + "\n";
                }
                output += lineDivider + "\n";

                ndef.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                output += "NDEF connect to tag IOException: " + e.getMessage() + "\n";
                output += lineDivider + "\n";
            } catch (FormatException e) {
                output += "NDEF connect to tag RunTimeException: " + e.getMessage() + "\n";
                output += lineDivider + "\n";
            }
        }
        
        // final output
        String finalOutput = output;
        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            textView.setText(finalOutput);
        });
        // output of the logfile to console
        System.out.println(output);
        // a short information about the detection of an NFC tag after all reading is done
        playBeep();
    }

    /**
     * When the activity returns to foreground the ReaderMode gets enabled. Here I'm setting all flags,
     * meaning that all NFC technologies are allowed to get detected. If you remove e.g. the NfcA class
     * you won't detect NTAG21x tags anymore.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (myNfcAdapter != null) {
            if (!myNfcAdapter.isEnabled())
                showWirelessSettings();
            Bundle options = new Bundle();
            // Work around for some broken Nfc firmware implementations that poll the card too fast
            options.putInt(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_READER_PRESENCE_CHECK_DELAY, 250);
            // Enable ReaderMode for all types of card and disable platform sounds
            // The option NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK is NOT set
            // to get the data of the tag after reading
            myNfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(this,
                    this,
                    NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_B |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_F |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_V |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_BARCODE |
                            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS,
                    options);
        }
    }

    /**
     * When the activity gets inactive the ReaderMode is disabled
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (myNfcAdapter != null)
            myNfcAdapter.disableReaderMode(this);
    }

    /**
     * If the onResume() method detects that the NFC option is not enabled this method will forward you
     * to the Settings to enable NFC.
     */
    private void showWirelessSettings() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You need to enable NFC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public static String byteToHex(Byte input) {
        return String.format("%02X", input);
        //return String.format("0x%02X", input);
    }

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        if (bytes == null) return "";
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : bytes)
            result.append(Integer.toString((b & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        return result.toString();
    }

    public void playBeep() {
        ToneGenerator toneGen = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
        toneGen.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_PIP, 150);
    }
}

Michael

Thank you Michael for your comprehensive example! However, I have to admit that I did not implement it like this. I found a resource on github (NFCReader by mueller-ma) that I could use as a basis for my app. The implementation does also identify the tag as unknown but it still is able to determine the UID and that is all I need. As this is only a small project of mine I will currently stick to this version. Nevertheless, your code might be valuable to others or even myself at a later point in time.
